# Build and Run iOS7 app through command line

Tags: ios, shell, command-line

I want to build, run and publish iOS7 app using the command line tool. I am not getting any good sources for it. Can someone help me out with a good tutorial which will help me in writing a shell script to build my xcode project through command line and not through xcode build option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has a well documented tutorial on this :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

The build command goes like this :

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyiOSApp build
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. It is helpful.